# Processing list in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to process the data from a `method()` in golang, the output is in this format which is a sample one.

Edit:
The function is :

```
func MethodProcess()
{
  dataList := dataList{}
  //Call webservice method
  webres = MethodFromWeb()
    err := xml.Unmarshal(webres, &dataList)
  return dataList
}
```

The output:

```
{{arg1}desc[{ High Low [InnerDescription]}]}
```

The output is not basically in the json format ,so If I want to extract the data as "High",in what format is the data is in ?

is it possible to extract the data from it?

Comment: What package and method produces this output?

Comment: is not clear what you are asking here

Answer (score 3):

I don't recognise that data format.

You can either parse it with a grammar you make using [yacc](https://golang.org/cmd/yacc/).

Or use the brutal minimalism of [regexp](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/)

([Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/j9IbjaeE7_))

```
in := `{{arg1}desc[{ High Low [InnerDescription]}]}`
matcher := regexp.MustCompile(`^\{\{(.*?)\}(.*?)\[\{\s*(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s*\[(.*?)\]\}\]\}`)
match := matcher.FindStringSubmatch(in)
fmt.Printf("matches = %#v\n", match[1:])
fmt.Printf("High = %q\n", match[3])
```

Which prints

```
matches = []string{"arg1", "desc", "High", "Low", "InnerDescription"}
High = "High"
```